# SQL Databases Live Synchronization

Tags: sql, database, azure, synchronization, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to achieve live (instantaneous) data synchronization between two SQL databases [3 source tables to 1 target table], the synchronized data come from 3 different tables in the source database and should go into one table. I have looked into some options and had those disadvantages:

1 - Azure Data Sync:
a- 5 minute intervals of synchronization
b- Synchronization between tables happen on a 1 to 1 bases.

2 - Azure Logic App:
a - SQL connector throttling issues

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @zach, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: Hi @zach, Can you tried external table concept?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can consider using Azure data factory to incrementally syncing data on-premise to Azure SQL. This [post](https://www.element61.be/en/resource/building-hybrid-cloud-syncing-premise-databases-microsoft-azure-cloud-using-azure-data) also introduces in detail how to implement the whole process.

There are two main ways of incremental loading using Azure and Azure Data Factory:

- One way is to save the status of your **sync in a meta-data** file. In this file you would save the row index of the table and thus the ID of the last row you copied. Every time you want to add the newest data to the cloud, you look up the progress (latest row) and start from there (e.g. row IDs bigger than X). This process is out of scope in this article but is extensively explained in the Microsoft documentation. (Use a meta-data file when your table doesn't have an 'updated timestamp'.)
- Another way to do it is by using **tumbling windows**. Tumbling windows are time windows that do not overlap and are completely inclusive. As the image below shows, this means that every window will start at the end of the previous window.
  [image]